# Как превратить строку utf-16 в верстку

Tags: javascript, json

Нужно динамически рендерить элементы в браузере. С сервера приходит верстка в юникоде. Как преобразовать строку вида

\u003c\u0064\u0069\u0076\u003e\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074\u003c\u002f\u0064\u0069\u0076\u003e

В < div>test< /div> ?
Спасибо

Comment: Это не UTF-16, это обычный экранированный юникод

Comment: Вопрос остается открытым

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356493/decode-utf-8-with-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @abakan с сервера точно приходит только строка в таком виде, а не, например, JSON? Нельзя ли переделать сервер, чтобы он возвращал JSON?

Comment: json содержащий в себе строку в таком формате

Comment: выше скинули ссылку, будет вот так decodeURI("\u003c\u0064\u0069\u0076\u003e\u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074\u003c\u002f\u0064\u0069\u0076\u003e") Только почему сервер экранирует строку?

Comment: @abakan ну так тогда обыкновенный JSON.parse прекрасно всё раскодирует

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы не выдергиваете подстроками из JSON регулярками?